# Entity framework: One to one relationship, being able to navigate for both directions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, associations, one-to-one

Hi I have a Person and Passport entities. I created one 2 one association between them and it is working great. I can navigate from Person to Passport, but from Passport to Person is returning null. Here is how I did the mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasOptional(p => p.Passport)
.WithOptionalPrincipal(p => p.Person);
```

Here are the entities:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Passport Passport { get; set; }
}

public class Passport
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Number { get; set; }

    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

What should I do to be able to navigate both directions?

Comment: Please, could you show your entities?

Comment: @octavioccl I updated my post accordingly!

Comment: mmm... try adding `virtual` keyword to your navigation properties, in both entities: `public virtual Person Person { get; set; }`

Comment: @octavioccl That fixed the issue. Can you explain how putting the virtual keywords fixed the problem? I used the virtual properties before, but not for this purpose.

Comment: Ok, I will elaborate an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is due to you are missing one of the requirements of lazy loading, which is "all navigation properties must be `virtual`". Entity Framework creates proxies for POCO entities if the classes meet these requirements and those proxy classes are who let you load the related entities at run-tine, which are who implemented this feature called [lazy loading](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/lazy-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx)

You will find all those requirements in the following [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd468057(v=vs.110).aspx)